# Eclipse - glassfish can't start because org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

i use eclipse for my JavaEE project

its working fine, then my computer shutdown unexpectedly

then when i start glassfish server from eclipse

i receive following error

```
   Unable to start server due following issues:
   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; 
   Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

how to fix it?

before my computer shutdown unexpectedly, everything is working fine with glassfish

Comment: @Mustafasabir no i dont try it because of the complexity.. i will try it later if there is no way out.. is there any other way that i can try without re-installing glassfish sir?

Comment: had same problem. Really wish there was a way out of this without reinstalling GF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error pops up when there are unexpected spaces or characters in xml file, it seems like  your xml file(s) got corrupted. Most probably this one: -`glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml`

Referring solution provided on this [link](http://lukasz-wozniak.pl/2013/04/06/glassfish-3-backup-command/) , the most appropriate thing that can be done seems to be, to create a new instance of the server and try deploying on it.